# Django permission management

Tags: django, tastypie

The Django document says, "Permissions are set globally per type of object, not per specific object instance. For example, it’s possible to say “Mary may change news stories,” but permissions don’t let you say “Mary may change news stories, but only the ones she created herself” or “Mary may only change news stories that have a certain status, publication date, or ID.”".

My problem is

1. how to grant user permissions to edit resources he created?

even though I'm using tastypie to implement a server for my ios app, I don't understand tastypie DjangoAuthorization, so I think I should learn how to mangage permission in Django first.

Comment: You tagged this as tastypie, even though you don't specifically reference that in your question; are you using tastypie? If so, your resource can implement its own authorization to do exactly what you want; this only applies to tastypie's generated web services, however, rather than to other views or templates you might have in your app.

Comment: What you're looking for is 'row level permissions'. I'm also looking into how to implement it in tastypie, so I can't help you with the specifics yet. Perhaps knowing what to search for is helpful for you though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that entry on tastypie cookbook http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources